# Is it possible to playback a podcast from an XNA Or Silverlight application on Windows 7 Phone?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xna-4.0, podcast

Is it possible to enumerate audio and/or video podcasts that exist locally on a Windows 7 Phone?  I'd like to play an audio or video podcast in my application.

Comment: What do you mean by 'enumerate podcasts'? Do you mean play video? Fetch data from a database? This question is a little broad.

Comment: I've edited the question.  Let me know if that's still too broad.

Comment: I found a duplicate that was asked Pre-Mango: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721776/how-do-you-access-podcasts-in-wp7

Answer (score 0):

I still don't fully understand what you mean by video podcasts, but from what I can see, you want to find every video and audio file in storage on the phone, and play them all back? If so, you would be crazy to try to find every file at runtime each time, rather you should create a database (similar to iTunes or Windows media player) on the first run. As for playing the video and audio, the audio is easy enough and there are many tutorials on playing sounds with XNA, like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203895%28v=xnagamestudio.31%29.aspx), and you can find a tutorial for video playback [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/iersoy/how-to-use-video-in-xna/).

Comment: It's possible to subscribe to audio or video podcasts on your Windows 7 Phone (see http://www.microsoft.com/windowsphone/en-us/howto/wp7/music/subscribe-to-podcasts.aspx, "Subscribe to your favorite audio and video podcasts directly from Marketplace")

Comment: Oh, I don't have a windows phone. Well AFAIK you can use filestreams with silverlight on a phone.